# Using custom log4j logging function

Tags: java, log4j

I was using log4j like this:

```
public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("getClass()");
log.info("ddd");
```

Now I decided to have some custom logging function like:
`log.info("ddd",true);` That overloads standart `info` one.

And add some job inside of it that depends on on boolean parameter.

I found that info function is defined in `Category` class. Is it good approach creating from `Category` derived class? And I suppose to use logging with my new function I need to create new `Logger` class?

Comment: Why do this? If you need custom logging, create a custom logging facade. Create a `interface MyLogger` and create an implementation backed by Log4j. But generally, there shouldn't be logic in logging, it should be exactly that - logging.

Comment: if I create facade I will loose many nice features from Logger. I would like to use all functionality of Logger plus I would like to ask Logger to make my small job when it does its nice logging.

Comment: Why would you lose any features of Log4j? This is exactly that [SLF4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) does and it _adds_ features. You ideally want to avoid tying your code directly to a particular logging library if possible.

Comment: Ok, I have SLF4j bounded to log4j. But how to solve my problem - ad my additional functionality to logging functions?